# How to read a file in a module by its relative path to the module?

Tags: python, file, directory

The directory structure:

```
├--- mod
|    ├--- __init__.py
|    └--- abc.data
└--- test.py
```

__init__.py:

```
with open("abc.data", 'r') as f:
    pass # read and process the data
```

test.py:

```
import mod
```

The program above is expected to read the data in the file `abc.data`, but it gives an error instead:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'abc.data'
```

And this is because the **current directory** of Python interpreter is the parent directory of `test.py`.

So how to read `abc.data` in the module `mod` regardless of the location of `test.py`?

---

Actually the following code works:

__init__.py:

```
import os
filepath = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)), "abc.data")
with open(filepath, 'r') as f:
    pass # read and process the data
```

But this solution is a bit dirty especially when there are many files to be read in `__init__.py`. Is there a more elegant solution?

Comment: It's not more elegant, but if you have many files to read in `__init__.py`, you could just store the path to the directory in a variable, e.g. `root = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))` and then just use `abc_path = os.path.join(root, "abc.data")`. At least it saves some error prone typing or copy/pasting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that's as good as it gets.  Even larger libraries use the same method:

```
# Extracted From selenium/webdriver/firefox/firefox_profile.py

# ...
if not FirefoxProfile.DEFAULT_PREFERENCES:
            with open(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),
                                   WEBDRIVER_PREFERENCES)) as default_prefs:
                FirefoxProfile.DEFAULT_PREFERENCES = json.load(default_prefs)
# ...
```

Another example:

```
# Extracted from pipenv/vendor/yaspin/spinners.py

# ... 
THIS_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
SPINNERS_PATH = os.path.join(THIS_DIR, "data/spinners.json")
# ...
```

If it was an importable object (e.g. `.py` files) then you can use `.` conventions to indicate the relative path.